# I run the tomcat in Docker but when I close the terminal it stops, so how to make it run continuous

Tags: docker, tomcat8

I run the tomcat server 8 in docker, it runs correctly when I run using docker run command and the command prompt don't come back, now I press ctrl+c and prompt come back, but now tomcat server has stopped so when I check on http://localhost:8080 the tomcat page not appear. So how to make it run continuously or so called system level process in container.
Here is my docker file. Help me with this

```
FROM scratch
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN mkdir /opt/java8
RUN mkdir /opt/tomcat8

ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/java8
ENV CATALINA_HOME /opt/tomcat8

ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/bin

ADD jdk1.8.0_112 /opt/java8
ADD apache-tomcat-8.0.38 /opt/tomcat8

ADD M_UserTP.war /opt/tomcat8/webapps

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Running startup.sh not even help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker run` distinguishes between a *foreground* and a *detached* mode ([source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d)). Your troubles are caused by the fact that you run the container in *foreground* mode. To run it in the background as a daemon, use the *detached* mode:

`docker run -d [IMAGE] [COMMAND]`

This starts the container in the background, and keeps it running  as long as the process inside continues to run. You can see what's going on inside the container by either looking at its logs (`docker logs [CONTAINER_ID]`) or by jumping on a shell inside the container (`docker exec -it [CONTAINER_ID] /bin/sh`).

If you are done working with the container, use `docker stop [CONTAINER_ID]` to stop it. If you are unsure whether you have a container running, use `docker ps`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ctrl` + `c`, you should type `ctrl` + `p` and `ctrl` + `q` to detach

Answer (score 1):

**There are 2 ways to get into a running container:**

> 1) [Attach to the process/container](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/attach/)

**Used to attach your terminal’s standard input, output, and error to a running container using the container’s ID or name.** This allows you to view its ongoing output or to control it interactively, as though the commands were running directly in your terminal.

To stop a container, use CTRL-c. This key sequence sends SIGKILL to the container. **You can detach from a container and leave it running using the CTRL-p CTRL-q key sequence.**

```
# docker run -it ubuntu:15.0 /bin/bash
root@9391b08536ae:/#  

# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
9391b08536ae        ubuntu:15.0         "/bin/bash"         6 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0/tcp               confident_albattani


# docker attach 939
root@9391b08536ae:/# 
root@9391b08536ae:/# exit
exit
root@labadmin-VirtualBox:~/RAGHU/python# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

> 2) [Execute the container](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)

**The docker exec command runs a new command in a running container.**

```
# docker exec -it 939 /bin/bash
root@9391b08536ae:/# exit
exit


# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
9391b08536ae        ubuntu:15.0         "/bin/bash"         25 seconds ago      Up 25 seconds       0/tcp               confident_albattani
```

Hope this helps.